# How do I convert Hindi language with Text-to-Speech?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I tried text to speech but it is speaking Hindi only if Google Text-to-Speech is present. But in my phone only Pico TTS is there. So it's not speaking Hindi script.
Please help me how speak Hindi text without Google TTS or in TTS.